# Linux shell script to download file(s) from server to PC while connected with putty

Tags: linux, shell, download, ftp

I am connected to a server through putty, and I want to download (to my PC) certain files on a regular basis using a shell script. Specifically, these are the files...

```
ls -t ~/backup | head -n2
```

What is the best strategy for this? I was trying with command line FTP but I am prompted to login to something. I'm already logged into the server that has the files I need to download, so I am missing something.

Comment: Do you currently log in using ssh keys and so no password?

Answer (score 0):

The SSH protocol can be a good way, with `scp` command. You can take a look at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

To automate the process and script a solution, you will need use password-less ssh and ssh keys.

The first step will be to get the list of files to copy and so:

```
fils=$(ssh username@host ls -t ~/backup | head -n2)
```

Then once we have the files read into a variable fils, we can loop on the entries and run a secure copy command:

```
while read fyle
do
   scp username@host:~/"$fyle" "$fyle"
done <<< "$fils"
```